# How to get long-lived access token Google API

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, google-docs-api, google-data-api

In the Google documentation it says

```
// Once the user authorizes with Google, the request token can be exchanged
// for a long-lived access token.  If you are building a browser-based
// application, you should parse the incoming request token from the url and
// set it in OAuthParameters before calling GetAccessToken().
```

but it doesn't say or show how to do that :(

Does anyone know how to do that for a desktop app?

Code samples are more than welcome!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok , After some time i solved it.

After you get an access token , you also get an refresh token. store that token!

Also do this `parameters.AccessToken = StoredRefreshToken` and `parameters.RefreshToken = StoredRefreshToken`
before you make your next request call `OAuthUtil.RefreshAccessToken(parameters);`

And then you should be good to make a request!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [AuthSub with the .NET Client Library](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/authsub_dotnet). If so, try this

```
if (Request.QueryString["token"] != null)
{
    String token = Request.QueryString["token"];
    Session["token"] = AuthSubUtil.exchangeForSessionToken(token, null).ToString();
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, true);
}​
```

P.S: The above link has the complete listing of code.

Comment: i get "Attempt to upgrade a non-upgradeable token" and this is for web app , i'm making a desktop app.